# Regular Expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following python code that will try to read an input file and find the following instances of the give regular expression:

```
[fF][eE][bB]([1-2][0-9]|[0-9]
```

I have written the following python code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys

textFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
fileText = textFile.read()
textFile.close()
matches = re.findall("[fF][eE][bB] ([1-2][0-9]|[0-9])",fileText)
print matches
```

and my input file is :

```
1 2 3 the
the quick 2354
feb 1 
feb 0
feb -10
feb23
feb 29
feb 3
february 10
```

However when I run my code I get following output: `['1','29', '3']`

I want my output to be more like `['feb 1', 'feb 29', 'feb 3']`

I am not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should [read the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall). `re.findall` returns only capture groups when there are in the expression. You should simply remove the capture group from your regex:

```
matches = re.findall("[fF][eE][bB] (?:[1-2][0-9]|[0-9])",fileText)
                                    ^^
```

That said, this regex will also match `feb 0`, so you might want to use

```
[fF][eE][bB] (?:[1-2][0-9]|[1-9])
                            ^
```

Instead.

Now, you can make the regex shorter if you use `re.IGNORECASE` (to make the regex match both uppercase and lowercase characters), and if you use a loop to read the file contents (this is more efficient for large files). Also, it's a good practice to raw your regex patterns:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as textFile:
    for line in textFile:
        matches = re.match(r"feb (?:[1-2][0-9]|[1-9])", line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if matches:
            print matches.group()
```

And of course, you can put the matches in a list too if you need a list in the end.

Comment: +1 Awesome post, it contains so much information, much of it already known to me, but more than expected was unknown. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around the entire expression in order for `matches` to contain the matched text. There will be one match group for each pair of parens; you can use `(feb (?:[12][0-9]|[1-9]))` to have grouping without capturing for the second group.

However, given your examples, perhaps you actually want to print the entire input line when there is a match?

Comment: Note also the `1-9` to avoid matching `feb 0`. If you want to match that as well, the expression could be simplified to `(feb [12]?[0-9])`.

Comment: Yeah, `re.IGNORECASE` too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print like this,

```
['feb 1', 'feb 29', 'feb 3']
```

You can use the below code,

```
    matches = re.findall("(feb (?:[12][0-9]|[1-9]))",fileText)
    print matches
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
(feb\s[1-9][0-9]?)
```

Matches: feb followed by a space and a digit between 1 and 9 and then any other optional digit between 0 and 9.

Try:

```
matches = re.findall(r'(feb\s[1-9][0-9]?)',fileText)
print matches
>>> ['feb 1', 'feb 29', 'feb 3']
```

Caveat: this won't solve for text like "feb 51"

[See it in action](http://regex101.com/r/pL0cC4)